# How to insert a line in the file left.phtml?

Tags: layered-navigation, phtml

I have a code and a part of it. But I do not know how to combine.
I try to show the subcategory of the category ID 3.

```
<div class="block block-layered-nav block-layered-nav--no-filters">    
<div class="block-content toggle-content open">    
    <dl id="narrow-by-list2">    
        <dt><?php echo $this->__('Меню') ?></dt>    
        <dd>    
            <ol>    
            <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>    
                <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>    
                <li>    
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($_category)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>>    
                        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) ?>    
                        <span class="count">(<?php echo $_category->getProductCount() ?>)</span>    
                    </a>    
                </li>    
                <?php endif; ?>    
            <?php endforeach ?>    
            </ol>    
        </dd>    
    </dl>    
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list2')</script>    
</div>
```

And this line:`$categoryId = 3;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
$childrenCategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in catalog/navigation/left.phtml, correct? A few lines above the HTML that you posted you should see this line:

```
<?php $_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories() ?>
```

Replace that with your code, changing your $childrenCategories to $_categories, like so:

```
<?php
$categoryId = 3;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
$_categories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
?>
```

Comment: Tell me, please, how to show all subcategories? Category ID3 (level 1) -> Category (level 2) -> Subcategories (level 3)

Comment: Sorry, didn't see this comment at the time. If you want to show all categories at all levels you'll need a recursive function, something like:

`function listAllSubs($catId) {
   $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);
   $subs = $category->getChildrenCategories();
   if ($subs->getSize()) {
      echo '<ul>';
      foreach ($subs as $sub) {
         echo '<li>'.$sub->getName().'</li>';
         listAllSubs($sub->getId());
      }
      echo '</ul>';
   }
}

$rootCatId = 1; /* or whatever it is in your store */
listAllSubs($rootCatId);`

Comment: ^^ by the way the above comment is my quick and dirty "answer" that doesn't take certain implications into account (such as how long it takes to run, how much memory it uses etc). If anyone wants me to explain in more detail and with better formatting please post a question (better yet, find an existing one, it's bound to be out there already) and add a link to that question in this comment thread. I'll try to answer a bit quicker than I did to @Agestor's query above!